# Eclipse IDE not warning me if file has been modified outside its environment

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse environment doesn't load or warn me if the file has been modified outside its environment, instead its asking me if I should overwrite the one of disk with my changes. This used to work properly, but not sure why its failing now.

Comment: Which Eclipse on which platform---Indigo?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I recall, this is the 'normal' behavior, and this is the warning that you get if the file on disk was externally changed and you have made changes to the source in an opened editor.

There is one thing that may help (at least on stratup):
Go to Window -> Preferences and click General->Workspace.
Make sure that 'Refresh automatically' is check (by default it's not).

Cheers

Comment: Refresh does an check only on startup, not sure if it does while the IDE is UP. Note: previously I used to get a warning if I do a refresh of my source code from SVN and the IDE used to warn that it has changed in the disk and if I wanted to re-load, now it doesn't.

Comment: Even checking on startup is not the default.  Refresh automatically is the only solution to your problem, apart from using an SVN plug-in that updates the workspace in such a way that Eclipse knows about the changed files correctly.